# ascii shift program works for almost the whole string

Tags: java, loops, intellij-idea, ascii, caesar-cipher

I have to write a program (method thingy, excuse my noobness)that has a char array as an input, converts it to numbers according to its ascii value, shifts it to whatever the inputed shift value (can be positive or negative) is, and then decrypts it.

the problem with my program is that it works for nearly the whole array, but for certain test cases fails for the last few characters. Can anyone help point out flaws in my logic?

For example, `sgADF@#$5^^%{].` reads `sgADF@#$5^^%{g3` after decryption (i.e. `].` is replaced with `g3`).

I'm pretty sure there's no problem with my decrypt. it just inputs the line array (should be char) into the encrypt with the opposite shift value.

```
//converts char values to numbers and stores them in hold array
    for (int x = 0; x < line.length; x++) {
        char character = line[x];
        int ascii = (int) character;
        hold[x] = ascii;
    }
[![enter image description here][1]][1]//shift to numbers
    for (int x = 0; x < line.length; x++) {

        //case1
        if (nshift < 0) {
            while (hold[x] + nshift < THIRTY_TWO) {
                nshift = nshift + NINETY_FIVE;
                    // nshift = copy of shift (checkstyle)
            }
            hold[x] = hold[x] + nshift;

        }


        //case2,
        if (shift > 0) {
            while (hold[x] + nshift > ONE_TWENTY_SIX) {
                nshift = nshift - NINETY_FIVE;
                    // nshift = copy of shift (checkstyle)
            }

            hold[x] = hold[x] + nshift;

        }

    }
    for (int x = 0; x < hold.length; x++) {
        char digit = (char) hold[x];
        out[x] = digit;
    }

    return out;
```

[image: shows tests cases][image]

Comment: Which test cases were failing? What did you expect to happen, and what happened instead? Also, images of text like this are strongly frowned upon because they're more difficult to read, can't be copied and pasted, and can't be searched for (which potentially makes it more difficult for future readers with similar problems to find).

Comment: sgADF@#$5^^%{]. reads sgADF@#$5^^%{g3 after it is encrypted and then decrypted

Comment: So, the `]` is replaced with `g3` (if I'm reading this correctly)?

Comment: " ]. " (two characters) is replaced with " g3 "